# Round to nearest integer strange results

Tags: haskell, floating-point

Is there an official specification for the `round` function in Haskell? In GHCi version 7.0.3 I see the following behaviour:

```
ghci> round (0.5 :: Double)
0
ghci> round (1.5 :: Double)
2
```

Since both 0.5 and 1.5 are representable exactly as floating point numbers, I expected to see the same behaviour as in Python 2:

```
>>> round(0.5)
1.0
>>> round(1.5)
2.0
```

Is there a rationale for the difference, or is it a quirk of GHCi?

Comment: Note that Python 3 behaves in the same way as GHCi here.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Do you happen to know why IEEE specifies rounding to the even number? It seems unintuitive to me - either of round up or round away from zero would make more sense.

Comment: I suppose it makes it more likely that rounding errors will cancel out if you round a bunch of numbers and then sum them up...

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Yes, it's to avoid bias introduced by rounding. It's often called 'Banker's rounding' (though, iirc, in the EU, round-half-away-from-zero is mandatory for financial applications). With round-half-away-from-zero, it cancels out only if the values are half negative and half positive, with half-to-even, it cancels out more often.

Comment: It's my understanding that rounding to the even number is the scientific standard. Rounding up is common in grade school for some reason but is otherwise just another convention.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's in the specification. You can see it in section 6.4.6 of [the Haskell report](http://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf):

> `round x` returns the nearest integer to `x`, the even integer if `x` is
>   equidistant between two integers.

As pointed out by [@dflemstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230461/dflemstr), this is in accordance with the [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#Rounding_rules).

Comment: This is according to the IEEE 754 floating point rounding mode standard.

Comment: Here's the code for `round` if anyone is interested: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Real.html#round the check for even is quite obvious there.

Comment: FWIW, for comparison, the python round() is a wrapper around the C99 round() function, which on an implementation that follows C99 Annex F rounds ties away from zero.

Comment: @Poindexter The link is dead. Long live the link!